# Ender 3 Pro prints leaning

Tags: creality-ender-3

Hello 3D printing experts...I am stuck on my 1st print not coming out right.  After two prints, I finally got the X axis belt tight enough to print the test pig and it came out quite well.  I tried to print a filter holder for a PPE mask (makethemasks dot com) - the prints keep leaning and I can't seem to get this filter holder printed.  I have adjusted the eSteps in various increments, still leaning.  I have made belt adjustments too.  I have emailed Creality as well since I have heard that their support might assist as well.  I was so excited when the pig finally printed properly and now I am struggling to get even once mask filter holder printed after hours of tinkering and reprinting.  I have also tried to print the ear saver (show as a long mass in the lower left corner of the photo), the base stuck to the item and I could not get it loose, it just fused together.  sigh.  I know 3D printing is supposed to be a fun hobby, but I am sure getting off to a rocky start.  I want to print PPE masks and be helpful to my community by donating to hospitals.  I hope one of the settings recommendations help.  I tried to research adjusting the jerk and acceleration settings.  Not sure what to set those to with the Ender 3 Pro.

[image]

Comment: Welsome to 3DPrinting.SE! To dial your printer in, you usually start by printing calibration prints, e.g. [calibration cubes](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1278865). It is difficult for others to comment on the printer if the basic working of the printer is not okay. Furthermore, what is the image trying to explain with the numbers? For us it is a guess how the square filter holders are oriented onto the build plate (e.g. Y from bottom to top and X from left to right?).

Comment: Along with what @0scar is stating, if you are using the gcode directly from the site, you might see if you can get the STL file and re-slice it using Cura (or one of the other slicers) which would be setup for your printer. If using pre-sliced gcode, the file itself may not be providing you exactly what you need and is what is causing the issues.

Comment: Without more information, this question cannot be answered. Please explain what the numbers are, what the orientation of the prints in the build surface was and what kind of basic settings you used to slice the models e.g. temperatures, speeds, see [this question](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/helpful-templates-help-us-help-you).

Comment: Steps-per-mm doesn't need to be adjusted, ever, unless you've made changes to the relevant mechanical parts. The values are determined by mechanical ratios. Extrusion amount will vary a bit by material because of compression of the material in the gear, but this is not a good reason to adjust esteps; just adjust flow % per material.

Comment: How did you print the mask inserts? Upright or flat (like laying now on the paper)?

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like layer shifting, both gradual and sudden.  This is frequently caused by excessive friction on one axis, the one along which the print is leaning.  You mentioned tightening the X-axis; if these are leaning along the X axis, chances are good the belt is too tight and causing something (either the belt or the toothed gear it is attached to) to rub against something else (the frame, the v-slot extrusion, the motor itself in the case of the belt gear).

Both the X and Y axes should be fairly easy to move by hand with the power off.  Feel for any points where that isn't true.